# Why am I losing the column names using the .apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

please look at the code below and tell me why and how to correct the fact that I am losing columns when I use the .apply function:

```py
def compute_dayi_past_forecasts_assign_to_df(self):
        print ("Reverse engineering day_i past forecasts & exporting to dftrain.csv ...")
        
        self.simplifieddf = self.data[self.data["leadtime_hour"]==0]
        print (self.data)
        print(self.simplifieddf)
        self.simplifieddf.reset_index()
        print(self.simplifieddf)
        self.simplifieddf = self.simplifieddf[["dateiminusonepm25dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusoneno2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusoneo3dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusonepm10dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusonecodayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusoneso2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminustwopm25dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminustwono2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminustwoo3dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminustwopm10dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminustwocodayiforecast",\
                "dateiminustwoso2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusthreepm25dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusthreeno2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusthreeo3dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusthreepm10dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusthreecodayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusthreeso2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusfourpm25dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusfourno2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusfouro3dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusfourpm10dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusfourcodayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast",\
                "dateiminusonepm25dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusoneno2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusoneo3dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusonepm10dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusonecodayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusoneso2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusonepm25dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusoneno2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusoneo3dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusonepm10dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusonecodayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusoneso2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusonepm25dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusoneno2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusoneo3dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusonepm10dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusonecodayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusoneso2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminustwopm25dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminustwono2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminustwoo3dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminustwopm10dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminustwocodayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminustwoso2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminustwopm25dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminustwono2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminustwoo3dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminustwopm10dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminustwocodayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminustwoso2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminustwopm25dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminustwono2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminustwoo3dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminustwopm10dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminustwocodayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminustwoso2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusthreepm25dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusthreeno2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusthreeo3dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusthreepm10dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusthreecodayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusthreeso2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusthreepm25dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusthreeno2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusthreeo3dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusthreepm10dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusthreecodayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusthreeso2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusthreepm25dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusthreeno2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusthreeo3dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusthreepm10dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusthreecodayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusthreeso2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusfourpm25dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusfourno2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusfouro3dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusfourpm10dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusfourcodayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast7davg",\
                "dateiminusfourpm25dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusfourno2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusfouro3dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusfourpm10dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusfourcodayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast1Mavg",\
                "dateiminusfourpm25dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusfourno2dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusfouro3dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusfourpm10dayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusfourcodayiforecast1MMax",\
                "dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast1MMax"]] = self.simplifieddf.apply(self.compute_forecast_data_for_training_models, axis = 1).apply(pd.Series)
        
        print("\n")
        print(self.simplifieddf)
        print("\n")
        self.simplifieddf.to_csv('../data/train/all_data_merged/fr/dftrain.csv')
        return None

Reverse engineering day_i past forecasts & exporting to dftrain.csv ...
        level_0          nom  ...              dateiminusfourcodayiforecast               dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast
0             0          Ain  ...                                       NaN                                         NaN
1             1          Ain  ...                                       NaN                                         NaN
2             2          Ain  ...                                       NaN                                         NaN
3             3          Ain  ...                                       NaN                                         NaN
4             4          Ain  ...                                       NaN                                         NaN
...         ...          ...  ...                                       ...                                         ...
180475    39575  Haute-Corse  ...  (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)
180476    39576  Haute-Corse  ...  (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)
180477    39577  Haute-Corse  ...  (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)
180478    39578  Haute-Corse  ...  (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)
180479    39579  Haute-Corse  ...  (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)

[180480 rows x 124 columns]
        level_0          nom  ...               dateiminusfourcodayiforecast               dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast
0             0          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
5             5          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
10           10          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
15           15          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
20           20          Ain  ...  (149.03014431477732, 0.11197225229367214)   (1.3959629756333052, 0.05675848607515867)
...         ...          ...  ...                                        ...                                         ...
180455    39555  Haute-Corse  ...  (143.41060955577566, 0.10449042283729183)  (0.3608481368692678, 0.014600405538738473)
180460    39560  Haute-Corse  ...  (144.24718466236382, 0.10560423608756485)  (0.3614149127777261, 0.014623489145986743)
180465    39565  Haute-Corse  ...  (140.25963475581128, 0.10029522571053293)   (0.5594709101764878, 0.02268989914840522)
180470    39570  Haute-Corse  ...   (153.1138524276324, 0.11740928737937492)   (0.4827762961138283, 0.01956628658361586)
180475    39575  Haute-Corse  ...   (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)

[36096 rows x 124 columns]
        level_0          nom  ...               dateiminusfourcodayiforecast               dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast
0             0          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
5             5          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
10           10          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
15           15          Ain  ...                                        NaN                                         NaN
20           20          Ain  ...  (149.03014431477732, 0.11197225229367214)   (1.3959629756333052, 0.05675848607515867)
...         ...          ...  ...                                        ...                                         ...
180455    39555  Haute-Corse  ...  (143.41060955577566, 0.10449042283729183)  (0.3608481368692678, 0.014600405538738473)
180460    39560  Haute-Corse  ...  (144.24718466236382, 0.10560423608756485)  (0.3614149127777261, 0.014623489145986743)
180465    39565  Haute-Corse  ...  (140.25963475581128, 0.10029522571053293)   (0.5594709101764878, 0.02268989914840522)
180470    39570  Haute-Corse  ...   (153.1138524276324, 0.11740928737937492)   (0.4827762961138283, 0.01956628658361586)
180475    39575  Haute-Corse  ...   (154.95061300659887, 0.1198547441642122)  (0.2828088937316845, 0.011422029020511886)

[36096 rows x 124 columns]


              0        1  ... dateiminusfourcodayiforecast1MMax dateiminusfourso2dayiforecast1MMax
0           NaN      NaN  ...                               NaN                                NaN
5           NaN      NaN  ...                               NaN                                NaN
10          NaN      NaN  ...                               NaN                                NaN
15          NaN      NaN  ...                               NaN                                NaN
20      11.8516  2.93831  ...                               NaN                                NaN
...         ...      ...  ...                               ...                                ...
180455  4.24789  2.18165  ...                           172.461                           0.689131
180460  4.68711  1.80628  ...                           172.461                           0.689131
180465  7.63358  1.98594  ...                           172.461                           0.689131
180470  7.48639  1.99899  ...                           172.461                           0.689131
180475  8.15164  1.02853  ...                           172.461                           0.689131

[36096 rows x 192 columns]
```

As you can notice some of the output columns don't have a name and are incremented with digits. If I take away self.simplifieddf = self.data[self.data["leadtime_hour"]==0] and apply the function directly to self.data I keep all the column names, there are supposed to be more columns than the listed column names in between [[ ]]...

Comment: it's a bit TL;DR 1. I don't see why you have listed out so many columns for an assign when a join / merge would be simpler and avoid typos.  2. by apply you must mean `self.simplifieddf.apply(self.compute_forecast_data_for_training_models, axis = 1).apply(pd.Series)` where I can't see def for **compute_forecast_data_for_training_models**. I can only assume it returns a **dict** which is reason for `apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: I did a typo in my script by doing self.simplifieddf = self.simplifieddf[[... thank you for for noticing